# Large gaps when increasing font size

Tags: html, css

Whenever I increase the font size I get these large gaps between the `<p>` element and the next element. Can anyone tell me why?

[image]

```css
.text_box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 252px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 55px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text_box"> text </p>
<p> text </p>
```

Comment: define line height might fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `p` tag has `margin: 1em 0;` by default and `1em` is equal to font-size of an element (`55px` in your case). To avoid this try overriding the margin with some static value (`10px 0` for example)

Comment: to make this perfect I would explain a bit how em is related to font-size so we can clearly see why the gap is growing

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will auto inject css for certain elements.

Usually we use a CSS reset plus standard predefined styles for standard elements to suit our needs.

This should be the first thing you should do at the start of any project.

Also the issue with `EM` is that `EM` is a relative value that is based on the relative font size. So when you increase the font size you end up relatively increasing your margins because your margins are set to `EM`

`EM` will calculate `1em` to font value. so if your font is `12pt`, `1em` unit will equate to `12pt` so `6em` would = `72pts` and thus your margin would increase by `72pts`.

- [About CSS Resets](https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)
- [About Browser Styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_styles)
- [About CSS values & EM](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

In this case it was the margin causing the issue.

```css
.text_box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 252px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 55px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="text_box"> text </p>
<p> text </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**p** has *margin-block-start* and *margin-block-end* 1em; 
so you have to override it to 0em (like I inspector edit in blue line) the space will disappear.

[image]